# My WooCommerce cart totals table is doubling over?

Tags: woocommerce

Here is the issue:

http://i59.tinypic.com/ljgwp.jpg

As you can see, the cart totals doesn't look right at all. Everything else in my WooCommerce platform work perfectly. I don't know what to do or where to change it. I can't seem to find the CSS files.

How could I put the shipping and handling, the subtotal in borders so that it looks neat?

Comment: I don't see any error in it. 2*7.99 = 15.98. Cart Total = 15.98 + 0 (Free Shipping Local).

Comment: I meant the display format. Not the numbers.

Comment: Could I put the shipping and handling, the subtotal in borders so that it looks neat?

Comment: That was my question here, how?